# sed, awk, grep matching word 2 files

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Hope somebody can help.

I have two files.
`file-a` looks like

```
    bank
    sofa
    table
```

`file-b` is a "script". 
for the example it looks like:

```
    abcdfg bank
    kitchen abcdfg
    uhuh sofa :=
```

I need to know only the words in `file-a` that does not match any words in `file-b` and print this to `file-c`

I know have to do this in one single file, but not how to compare this to another file.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

In two step:

```
fgrep -f file-a -o file-b > this_words_from_file-a_are_in_file-b
sort file-a this_words_from_file-a_are_in_file-b | uniq -u
```

(The first searches for the words then outputs only the found ones, then with `sort` and `uniq` filtering out those.)

Comment: In that case you might want to read the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score 1):

```
fgrep -of file-a file-b | fgrep -vf - file-a
```

Looks first for all the words in file-a that are in file-b and then uses fgrep again to get the words that aren't in that list from file-a.

Answer (score 1):

This won't win code golf, but it makes only one pass on the data and doesn't waste any cpu time sorting:

```
awk '{ for( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) if( NR==FNR ) w[$i]=1; else delete w[$i] }
     END{ for( i in w ) print i}' file-a file-b > file-c
```

Note that the speedup is substantial.  With both `file-a` and `file-b` as `/usr/share/dict/words`, this awk solution ran on my system in 1.578s.  Time for John Lawrence's fgrep solution: 9.157s.  Time for Zsolt's fgrep | uniq: 4.951.

Answer (score 0):

```
join -1 1 -2 2 -v 1 <(sort file-a) <(sort -k2,2 file-b) > file-c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> fileC; cat fileA | while read ZWORD ; do fgrep -q "$ZWORD" fileB || echo $ZWORD >>fileC; done
$ cat fileC
table
```

*Clues*:

- `> fileC` creates an empty file
- `read` reads a line of `fileA` and puts it into variable `ZWORD`
- `fgrep` do not evaluate `$ZWORD` as regular expression
- `-q` is quiet
- `||` execute when preceding command fails

Comment: Do note that this creates a new `fgrep` (sub)process for every word... And itaretes for that word in the whole file again and again.